# Why my UIView inside UIScrollView doesn't respect its height contraint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, contentsize

I would like to make a simple `UIScrollView`.
For that I put an `UIView` inside it, and put all my components inside this `UIView`.

[image]

My problem is that I programmatically set the contentSize of my `UIScrollView` (and it works perfectly), but my `UIView` doesn't respect this new height... So my components in the bottom are not in my `UIView` but in my `UIScrollView` !

[image]

This is a problem because my `UISegmentedControl` ("Consommation/Emission") doesn't respond, contrary to the test `UISegmentedControl` ("First/Second") which works.

I put an equal height constraint between the `UIScrollView` and the `UIView` but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equal height constraint will make the frames the same size but will not cause the height of the view to equal the content size. I would create an actual height constraint for the view then make IBOutlet of that constraint and update it's constant when you set the scrollview's contentSize.height something like

```
self.viewHeightConstraint.constant = self.scrollView.contentSize.height;
```

wherever you're updating you scrollview's content size. I would say, when using auto layout, it's generally better to set or update constraints than setting frames. Setting frames tend to fight with the layout engine.

[image]

Find the constraint you set by checking the "Equal Heights" box. Check the "Height" box create an IBOutlet to that.

Comment: Works perfectly, I didn't know that we could make IBOutlet with constraints ! Thanks.

Comment: Edit: unfortunately I have a problem of constraints that I don't really understand : `<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f95f8d290d0 UIView:0x7f95f8dcae60.centerY == UIScrollView:0x7f95f9830000.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f95f8dcae10 UIView:0x7f95f8dcae60.height == UIScrollView:0x7f95f9830000.height + 808>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f95f8dc4140 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f95f8dcae60]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x7f95f9830000 )>`

Comment: When you added the explicit height constraint for the view did you remove the equal height to the scrollview? "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f95f8dcae10 UIView:0x7f95f8dcae60.height == UIScrollView:0x7f95f9830000.height + 808>" I think this line is the problem. Here you are saying you want the view to be equal to scrollview's height plus 808. You should remove this constraint and just have an absolute (i.e.. not relational to the scrollview) constraint for the height of the view and set that.

Comment: I understand the problem with the +808 (I think 808 is the actual real height I want), but I don't understand your solution I'm sorry... You tell me that I have to remove the equal height constraint which is an IBOutlet... So I don't need to create it in the storyboard ? In this way I added the constraint programmatically but I have an exception `UIView _isAutomaticContentOffsetAdjustmentEnabled]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fec6aa33590'`

Comment: You have one constraint that's saying set this thing's height equal to that's (that's like a relational constraint). But what you really want is one that says something like this thing's height is 808. So, I'm saying in storyboard remove the one you have and add the one you want then create an outlet for it.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you're saying (make an equal height constraint manually and dynamically). Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to fix that.
Listen to the change of the `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView`.
When contentsize change you catch it and you change your subview's frame(height, width..)

Like this:

```
[scrollView addObserver:self
             forKeyPath:@"contentSize"
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                context:NULL];
```

You  catch it here:

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath
                       ofObject:(id)object
                         change:(NSDictionary*)change
                        context:(void *)context {
    //change subview frame accordingly
}
```